# How to get desktop notification for new mails using mutt?

Tags: email, notification, mutt

I have switched my email client to mutt. Currently, I have a pull-workflow, meaning I have to check regularly if new mails have arrived. As email is a communication tool I barely use (or even avoid to use), I have a tendency to  not know about emails, which is bad.

This is why I would to get desktop notifications when new mails arrive matching a pattern. I also don't want to use a different mail client, like Thunderbird, I want to use mutt or maybe some other *only* for this purpose.

Is there a way I can configure mutt to run regularly and issue a desktop notification?

Comment: I have the same question. Does anybody have a working solution?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a 1-year old question, but aside from hacking a script to run mutt, you could just get some third-party app that checks your mail for you.

I use [Mail Notification](http://www.nongnu.org/mailnotify/) and I've been enjoying it, don't have to rely so much on my tablets informing me of mail.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to use offlineimap and then check the folders for new files (a new email in your inbox corresponds to a new file in the inbox folder). I would also highly recommend this if you do not check your email often because this way you can do everything very fast. The process is: download all your emails, and then process them fast (because they are already on your computer so mutt does not need to download everytime you open an email).

I recommend offlineimap + mutt-kz + notmuch. Your life will be so simple and happy.

Comment: This is a broad outline. It would be even more helpful if it includes the very steps until one gets email notifications.

Comment: @k0pernikus agreed. I think it is somewhere in-between a comment and an answer. I hope that it at least gets you started.